# How to declare structures of data that should only be used in a certain context, C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a rather general design problem and would like to solve it nicely. I'm writing remote control drivers in an embedded C++ project. There will be two types of remote control: joystick or radio. As I'd like the actual remote controller used to be transparent to an user-programmer, I'm also providing a base class for the two. So I'm going to have:

```
class RemoteControl {};
class JoystickControl : public RemoteControl {};
class RadioControl : public RemoteControl {};
```

I'd like RemoteContol to just have one public method: `RemoteControl.getInput()`. This method should return a structure of data in common format, eg. `RCInput`, so the above method's declaration would be:

```
class RemoteContol {
    virtual RCInput getInput();
};
```

Now, what's the best way to implement RCInput to be able to pass it to other classes' objects?
I thought an inner class / structure might be a solution, but I never used it yet so can someone please provide an example of implementation and usage?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
What I did before was (could be references, this is not important at the moment):

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} RCInput;

class RemoteContol {
public:
    virtual RCInput getInput() { return rcInput; }

private:
    RCInput rcInput;
};
```

But I thought this way I'm allowing users to create their own structures of type RCInput also not related to RemoteControl, so I was looking for a better design. But maybe there isn't any.

Comment: What goes inside RCInput? Something you want to hide? Something expensive to copy? (In fact, do you need to store and/or copy instances at all, or just pass const references around?)

Comment: RemoteControl::getInput should be virtual, I think. Maybe pure virtual. Regarding RcInput - you know better what fields it should contain.

Comment: It's not going to be a lot, so passing by value should be ok (but const references are ok as well). Nothing I want to hide goes there, it's just I'd like users not to be able to create their own instances of RCInput elsewhere - I thought this is good design, but maybe it isn't.
@Alex Farber: yes, it's going to be virtual.

Comment: You can make RCInput an abstract base class (or a normal base with protected constructors, or whatever) and really return a pointer to subclass if you want.  You still need to expose the input information somehow in the base class though, so it's not clear what you're hiding/encapsulating/abstracting by doing this.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent users to create RCInput instance? Is there some specific reason for this? RCInput looks like simple data container, without side effects, like rocket missile. C++ contains a lot of tricks, but we don't need to use all of them :)

Comment: Yes probably you're right. I'm also not a fan of over-designed code. It's just I'd like to learn what's best in this case. I added some clarification above to let you know what I already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that `RCInput` is going to be just data, so you can lay it out like that:

`RCInput.h` file

```
class RCInput
{
public:

    RCInput(double x, double y, double z);
    double x() const;
    double y() const;
    double z() const;
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
};
```

`RCInput.cpp` file:

```
RCInput::RCInput(double x, double y, double z)
: m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
{
}

double RCInput::x() const
{
    return m_x;
}

double RCInput::y() const
{
    return m_y;
}

double RCInput::z() const
{
    return m_z;
}
```

Don't make it a nested class, put it in its own header file. This way the clients which use the inputs do not depend physically on the `RemoteControl` class header file. In my experience, nested classes are usually an unnecessary complication, they should be best avoided unless really necessary (e.g. iterators in containers).

Also, don't yield to the temptation of making `RCInput` a struct with public data. You will lose all control over data accesses and creation of data, if you do so (no access logging in getters, no data validation in constructor, no place to set a debugger breakpoint). Remember that forward declaring a class/struct means that some other piece of code will need to be changed if you later decide to turn a `struct` into `class`, i.e. instead of

`struct RCInput;`

you will have to write

`class RCInput;`

It's better to make it a class from day 1.

If you worry about performance, you can inline the getters.

If you want to store `RCInput` in containers, add a public default constructor.

If you want to control who can create `RCInput`, make the constructor private and declare the creating classes as friends (but that makes storing it in containers difficult).

Comment: FYI iterators aren't usually nested classes.

Comment: @Ayjay OK, I had this impression based on my previous experience. But they don't have to be nested, true.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested.